# Asp.net mvc refresh page after HTTPPOST

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have problem with ASP.MVC. I call this action method from many page and I need after it refresh page, but I do not have link to page  where user was.

```
public ActionResult Hide<T>(T item, User user) where T : IHidable
{
    //... Some action
    return SomeThingWhatINeedAndRefreshPage();

    //Now I use this, but I do not want to redirect user to Home
    //return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the action and controller names like below and call `RedirectToAction` with these values.

`string actionName = this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();`
`string ctrlName= this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();`

Comment: This gives the current action and controller. What the OP is trying to achieve is to get the calling action so that he can redirect back to it.

Comment: Yes, true that. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to pass as additional parameter the original page where the client was:

```
public ActionResult Hide<T>(T item, User user, string returnUrl) where T : IHidable
{
    //... Some action

    return Redirect(returnUrl);
}
```

Now when you are building the url to this controller action simply include the `returnUrl` parameter from the current request.

Comment: So on evry usage this method in view I must add url as parameter?

Comment: Yes, you need to add it so that your controller action knows where to redirect to. Of course the parameter could be optional. If it is not provided, you could redirect to some default location.

Comment: You could try `return Redirect(Request.Referrer);`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me to retain my Query String:

```
return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
```

I based this off of a comment left by @YuriyP and decided to make it a full Answer.
This probably breaks some pattern for development, because you may want to asynchronously update part of your page without a full postback.